# Анализатор кода php

Tags: статический-анализ, php, динамический-анализ

Есть ли анализаторы под win для обнаружения уязвимостей в php коде?

**дополнение**: не будем ограничивать круг поиска: нужна любая прога, которая может помочь найти в коде дыры.

Comment: ну же ребята.. как только дело доходит до вопроса посложнее "а как вывести 10 записей в sql запросе" - сразу тишина!

Comment: Какой бред, что значит "уязвимостей"? уязвимостей к чему?

Comment: в чем бред, сир? в коде могут быть уязвимости, для вас это новость?

Comment: То, что Вы хотите будет посложнее программы, которая по ТЗ писала бы код на ПХП за Вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Вы тут такой фарс развели, а сами поленились в гугл залезть.*

---

Из коммерческих вариантов анализаторов кода, которые проверяют на уязвимость типа `XSS`, `SQL-Injection` и менее распространенных, достаточно известен только [**CodeSecure.**](http://www.armorize.com/)

*Тем не менее, некоторый пайплайн из анализаторов кода вполне можно создать и на основе некоммерческих решений.* В идеальном вакууме имеет смысл выполнять 3 уровня валидации - статическую проверку кода без проверки на уязвимости утилитой типа `lint`, специализированную статическую проверку на уязвимости и внешнюю проверку финального сайта на дырки в безопасности.

- Для первого "рубежа" вполне можно воспользоваться [**phplint.**](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/)
- Для второго я бы выбрал бы что-нибудь из [**Yasca**](http://www.scovetta.com/yasca.html), [**Pixy**](http://pixybox.seclab.tuwien.ac.at/pixy/) или [**phpsat.**](http://www.program-transformation.org/PHP/PhpSat)
- В плане третьего рубежа существуют очень хорошие коммерческие решения типа [**XSpider**](http://www.ptsecurity.ru/default.asp) и в случае, если вы действительно заботитесь о безопасности, *возможно, покупка лицензии будет оправдана.*

---

**Разумеется, анализаторы кода, как и в случае, например, с `C++` *(`PVS Studio` / `lint`)* ни в коей мере не являются панацеей, разве что помогают находить глупые ошибки.**

Все, как и всегда, в руках разработчика.

---

*Отличную дискуссию на тему можно почитать на [**stackoverflow.com**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files)*

Answer (score 0):

В ZendStudio 5.5 был статический анализатор кода.

А вот то что вы просите - это несколько нереально, как мне кажется.

Проследить за огромной кучей объектов и цепочками вызовов (включая рефлексию) и понять, была ли заэскейплена переменная которую мы хотим вставить в sql запрос - нереально.

На мой взляд такого не существует.

Comment: Почему нереально, в теории очень даже реально: отследить, является ли участок запросом, если да - то каким, экранировать переменные в нем. Эскейп это только один из вариантов, существуют и другие варианты дырок в коде.

Comment: Хм, если реально, почему же вы тогда не сделали подобную программку. Думаю на нее бы и спрос был бы велик при цене огромной. И что значит "участок является запросом"? С точки зрения языка запрос - это строка (String, если угодно). Подобное если и можно сделать то сложность сего деяния будет NP, для решения которого потребуется вечность.

Comment: Ну если бы я был настолько компетентен, я бы и вопрос не задавал. Получается, таких программ вообще не существует? 
мне нужна прога, которая хоть как то сможет помочь выявить хоть какие то дыры. Все лучше чем вручную ковырять.

Comment: Есть множество других программ, которые помогут вам найти уязвимости, но скорее не самого кода, а его использования. Т.е. проанализировав ваш сайт, можно это выяснить.

Comment: не совсем понял, о чем вы..